# How to reset my Drive for Desktop storage?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

I have a problem where I'm unable to empty my trash in Google Drive. Somehow when I empty the trash, it'll appear empty and after refresh everything is there again. The storage use/allocation doesn't also change in size.

I have tried https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/emptyTrash a proposed solution here but no luck.

I am using Standard subscription of 200 GB

Comment: What type of account do you have (google one, workspace)? Also, how many files are to be deleted? Have you tried doing it in small chunks to see if that works?

Comment: Google One. Well, I could do it in chunks but it's really a lot of files, thus manually isn't that productive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Google One account, I would suggest you going to their support page [Google One Help](https://support.google.com/googleone/#topic=9171059) to see if they can help you with that.

**UPDATE**

I have found another link for Google One support where you can talk personally to a Google Expert:

- https://support.google.com/googleone/answer/9269729